# Android TextView not recognising Html

Tags: android, html, string, listview, twitter

I have a twitter function in my app which displays a public timeline of a specific user.

My goal is to detect all hashtags, mentions, links etc and wrap them in html to change their appearance.

SO far this has worked, all of the above a wrapped in Html however their appearance is not being changed. See below

[image]

Tweet class

```
public class Tweet {

@SerializedName("created_at")
private String DateCreated;

@SerializedName("text")
private String Text;


public String getDateCreated() {

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,  hh:mm a");

    String date = format.format(Date.parse(DateCreated));

    return date;
}

public StringBuffer getText() {

    Pattern mentionPattern = Pattern.compile("(@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");
    Pattern hashtagPattern = Pattern.compile("(#[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");
    Pattern urlPattern = Patterns.WEB_URL;

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(Text.length());
    Matcher o = hashtagPattern.matcher(Text);

    while (o.find()) {
        o.appendReplacement(sb, "<font color=\"#437C17\">" + o.group(1) + "</font>");
    }
    o.appendTail(sb);

    Matcher n = mentionPattern.matcher(sb.toString());
    sb = new StringBuffer(sb.length());

    while (n.find()) {
        n.appendReplacement(sb, "<font color=\"#657383\">" + n.group(1) + "</font>");
    }
    n.appendTail(sb);

    Matcher m = urlPattern.matcher(sb.toString());
    sb = new StringBuffer(sb.length());

    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "<font color=\"#EDDA74\">" + m.group(1) + "</font>");
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);

    //textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));



    return sb;
} 

public void setDateCreated(String dateCreated) {
    DateCreated = dateCreated;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    Text = text;
}


@Override
public String  toString(){


    return  getText()  + "\n"+ getDateCreated() ;

}

    }
```

OnPostExecute Method in my Twitter Fragment

```
        try{
        Twitter twits = jsonToTwitter(result);

        for (Tweet tweet : twits) {


            listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);   

            ArrayAdapter<Tweet> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tweet>(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item, twits);


            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }

        }catch(NullPointerException e){

            mProgressDialog.hide();
            System.out.println("No Network Available");

        }
    }
```

JSON data to twitter object method

```
        // converts a string of JSON data into a Twitter object
    private Twitter jsonToTwitter(String result) {
        Twitter twits = null;
        if (result != null && result.length() > 0) {
            try {
                Gson gson = new Gson();

                twits = gson.fromJson(result, Twitter.class);

            } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                // just eat the exception
            }
        }
        return twits;
    }
```

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 2):

`font` is not  supported from `Html.fromHtml`. You can find a list of supported tag [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. tried the tag '<b>' i wasn't clear in my question, I've tried to implement Html.fromHtml but am not sure how or where to do this.